# Can't connect to LocalDB from Visual Studio 2015

Tags: sql-server, c#, sql-server-localdb, visual-studio-2015

When I try to connect to the database, to which I was previously able to connect, I get the following error:

[image]

I tried to solve this by looking up other stackoverflow questions and online resources, but without success. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Version mismatch.

Comment: What troubleshooting have you done so far?

Comment: Thank you everyone for the comments, I updated to Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 through Tools -> Extensions and Updates and it fixed the problem and now the versions match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 852 is SQL Server 2016 - Your LocalDB is version 851 for VS2015

- You try change compatibility level(lower)

  ALTER DATABASE DatabaseName
  SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 120;
  GO

Compatibility level 120 is SQL Server 2014 - version is 782.

I hope that It will work.

Comment: Thank you, this is a solution as you have answered. However, I did it via updating Visual Studio 2015 to the latest Update 3 and it fixed the issue.